# Images Scaling Down in draw in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, imaging

Alright guys last little bit of this project I'll ask for help on I promise.
So I go to load the images, works fine however I notice upon loading that the dimensions of the image have been scaled down in the y to 300 (all are a constant value of 433) and up or down from their original width to 600. 
I'm using the following method to load them

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(imagePath, "*.JPG"))
{
    Image contents = Image.FromFile(file);
    treesImage[count] = contents;
    count++;
}
```

and this is the resulting image when I have it loaded.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q40kK.png

As you can see the image below the red rectangle is quite small

Any help would be appreciated. If you require any more information please post below and I'll make sure to edit the original question with the relevant information as soon as humanly possible.

EDIT: I am using a simple windows form application and not another graphical framework for my own reasons.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. I must assume you're using winforms because you don't know any other UI frameworks exist (otherwise you wouldn't be using winforms to begin with), and thus consider that tagging this question [C#] is enough. It is clearly not. There's no way any of us know whether you're using winforms, WPF, Silverlight, WinRT, Android, iOS, XBox, Webforms, MVC, amongst many others.

Comment: @Highcore: I've added in the question that I'm using Windows forms. I do not use other graphical frameworks because I do not know how to code in any other except in XNA, using the Ogre 3D engine(both would be useless for this project), Android(which this application is not being developed on this platform until a future date) and HTML5(same reason as Android)

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you are using a PictureBox control to display the image.

When someone chooses a tree from your map, you obviously set the PictureBox Image property to the image object referenced by the index in the array.  Use the Image object to set the ClientSize of the PictureBox control.

```
...
Image img = treesImage[idx];
MyPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal;
MyPictureBox.ClientSize = new Size(img.Width,img.Height);
MyPictureBox.Image = img;
...
```

Alternately you can define one size for your PictureBox and force all the images to be scaled to that size by setting the control SizeMode property to StretchImage declaratively.

I would recommend that you create a simple class (MyImageInfo for example) that would store the Path, Width, and Height of the images found in your first function into a list and then just as before when a user clicks to view an image you set the width and height of the PictureBox and then call the LoadAsync(path) method to get the image.  then you aren't storing all images in memory at once, just as you need them since it doesn't look like this requires a lot of quick jumping from image to image.

Comment: I'm not using a picture box however this does seem like a viable option. 
I'm using the g.drawImage() function with the image and a point

Comment: I would say you are making this much harder on yourself than you need to, haha